# Model constants undefined after loading Rails app environment into a Jupyter notebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jupyter-notebook

I come from a Python background and am learning Ruby on Rails.

I wanted to use Jupyter notebooks to manipulate Rails objects as a learning exercise. (I am following the [Rails Getting Started Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html).)

After reading several blog posts on how to load a Rails app environment for scripting, I managed to create model instances inside of cells in a Jupyter notebook.

In order to do so, however, I had to call `Rails.autoload "Article"` in order to create a new instance of an Article.

This is the code running inside of a Jupyter notebook with a Ruby 2.3 kernel. The Rails version is 4.2.6

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'development'

require ::File.expand_path('../config/boot', __FILE__)

require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment', __FILE__)

Rails.autoload "Article"  # if I omit this line, Article is an undefined constant

article  = Article.new(text: "test")
article.save
```

It seems like I am close to being able to manipulate Rails related objects in my Jupyter notebook.

My question is: What is missing so that I don't have to call `Rails.autoload "Article"` for Article or any other model?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution [here](http://techlife.cookpad.com/entry/201510-jupyter-and-rails).

Changing the pwd to the directory of the app seems to be the missing step.

```
FileUtils.cd('/home/ubuntu/projects/ruby-docker-heroku/blog')

require './config/boot'

require './config/environment'

Article # no more undefined constant error
```